# Django Bootstrap Grid all content breaks onto new line

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website using the Django framework where it will display a grid of places (3 per row) however the code below, every place ends up going onto a new line within the column.

```
<div class="site-container container-fluid">        
   <div class="row">            
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2">
         <div class="thumbnail">                    
            <a href="{% url 'sites:details' site.id %}">
               <img src="{{ site.site_picture}}" class="img-responsive">
            </a>        
            <div class="caption">
               <h2>{{ site.site_name }}</h2>
               <h4>{{ site.site_street }}</h4>


               <!-- View Details -->
               <a href="{% url 'sites:details' site.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">View Details&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In my browser I see the content I want however every site is on a new line in the column, whereas I would like it to be in a row of three and break onto a new line and then begin another row of three.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrN9p.png)

Comment: i didn't use bootstrap ever, but as i understand you use wrong class. As i understand you have use this class `.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4`. https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are executing all within the

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2">
```

If you inspect the browser do you see only one of these elements?  If so then that would be your problem.  What you want is something like,

```
<div class="site-container container-fluid">        
<div class="row">   
  LOOP OUTSIDE OF HERE!!!!!!!! <---------------------
  <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2">
     <div class="thumbnail">                    
        <a href="{% url 'sites:details' site.id %}">
           <img src="{{ site.site_picture}}" class="img-responsive">
        </a>        
        <div class="caption">
           <h2>{{ site.site_name }}</h2>
           <h4>{{ site.site_street }}</h4>


           <!-- View Details -->
           <a href="{% url 'sites:details' site.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">View Details&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

That way you will get multiple columns each holding its own content.